# Deadlock in child table while executing delete and insert statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, deadlock

I have these two below tables on which I am performing delete followed by an insert but intermittently deadlocks are being encountered.

Schedule.Assignments (parent table)

[image: 1]

Schedule.Schedules (child table):

[image: 2]

Intermittently two types of deadlocks are occurring on `schedule.Schedules` table (child) although the operation is being performed on `schedule.Assignments` table (parent). Both are having the same deadlock graph as shown below.

1. Deadlock between an Insert and Delete statements on `schedule.Assignments` table.
2. Deadlock between same Delete statement on `schedule.Assignments` table.

[Deadlock Graph]

[image: 3]

```
Deadlock Graph1 : https://pastebin.com/raw/ZpQUrjBV
Deadlock Graph2 : https://pastebin.com/raw/DhnuyZ7a
```

Stored procedure containing the insert and delete statements: https://pastebin.com/raw/6DNh2RxH

Query Execution Plan: [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJW1pzu0q)

**[Edit]**

Assignments Schema: [Assignments Schema](https://pastebin.com/raw/2xLkRRrY)

Assignments Indexes: [Assignments Indexes](https://pastebin.com/raw/0aTSfNKw)

Schedules Schema: [Schedules Schema](https://pastebin.com/raw/NVmLFRMy)

Schedules Indexes: [Schedules Indexes](https://pastebin.com/raw/Ee693qei)

What I am not able to understand as to why deadlock object is showing as child table whereas the process involved in the deadlock shows insert/delete on parent table.

Please share your thoughts as how to solve these deadlocks?

Comment: There is something weird going on: It looks a bit like a classic foreign-key deadlock, but you do already have an index on `ParentId`. The `DELETE SA` query is doing a hash join, along with an implicit conversion to `bigint` presumably from `int`, which doesn't make sense to me as it's not possible to have a foreign key on two different data types. Can you post the *full* table definitions (including indexes) for both `Assignments` and `Schedules`, using `Script Table As CREATE` in SSMS?

Comment: [Cascading Delete Troubles](https://forrestmcdaniel.com/2018/11/02/cascading-delete-troubles/)

Comment: @ErikDarling I think this would happen even without the cascade, you can also see it in the `INSERT` on the parent table

Comment: @Charlieface - Updated the full definition for table and indexes in the post. Please check.

Comment: Not sure why you removed essential details like the query plan, but I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your deadlocking is caused by a big table scan on `Schedules`. The scan happens in three different places in your procedure. What should happen instead is a simple `Nested Loops`/`Index Seek` on `ParentId`.

The reason you have a scan is because the join condition on `ParentId` is between a `nvarchar(50)` column and a `bigint`. I suggest you fix this by making `ParentId` a `bigint`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE schedule.Schedules
  ALTER COLUMN ParentId bigint NULL;
```

You may need to drop and re-create indexes or constraints when you do this.

---

As a side point, although it appears that you have an index on `schedule.Assignments (OldResourceRequestId)`, it is not unique. This is causing an `Assert` on the various subqueries to ensure only one row is returned, and may also be affecting query statistics/estimates.

I suggest you change it (if possible) to a unique index. If there are duplicates then you need to rethink these joins anyway, as you would get duplicate results or fail the `Assert`.

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Assignments_OldResourceRequestId] ON schedule.Assignments
(
    OldResourceRequestId ASC
)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON) ON PRIMARY;
```

---

You should also take note of your `IF` statements. They are not indented, and it is not clear that what is actually happening is that only the first statement afterwards is conditional, due to the lack of `BEGIN` `END`. As mentioned in the other answer, the `IF` may not be necessary anyway.

Comment: Instead of altering the datatype of that column, can I use the "TransactionId" column instead to perform the join? So the way the application works is like it will insert a record in Assignments table and then inserts a set of records in the Schedules table using the same TransactionId.

Assignments --> (1 : N) --> Schedules

Comment: Yes you could if that works with your data, but make sure it's the same type and it's indexed properly. Also your indexed view needs modifying also.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to be sure, but I'll tell you where I'd start.

1. Eliminate the IF EXISTS test.  Just go straight to the DELETE.  If the value isn't there, the DELETE will be quick anyway.  You're also not in a transaction, which leaves you open to the table changing between SELECT and DELETE.
2. Re-write the proprietary DELETE...JOIN as an ANSI DELETE using a WHERE EXISTS subquery. The proprietary version has problems whose details elude me right now.  Better to write it in a standard way, and not invite problems.

You say "child" and "parent" tables.  Does Schedules have a defined foreign key to Assignments?  It should.

I'm not sure those changes will eliminate the problem, but IMO they'll make it less likely.  You're increasing the atomicity by reducing the number of statements, and by eliminating branches you force each invocation of the procedure to execute the exact same logical sequence.

Comment: The `IF EXISTS` isn't present in the deadlock graph, and the query plan for it looks pretty efficient anyway (I agree that it should probably go). "The proprietary version has problems whose details elude me" like what? The only issue would be double-counting rows, but since you are deleting it doesn't matter much. Looks from the query plan that there is a foreign key, and this is *exactly* what is causing the issue, as the cascaded delete is causing an index scan and hash join for some reason.

Comment: I don't remember anymore what exact problems are manifested by the T-SQL delete-join syntax, but I do remember they're solved by using ANSI syntax.  So I learned the ANSI syntax, and avoided problems that way.  This *might* be one.  That hash join is a clue, too.  If the DML indicates cascading deletes, I would change it not to, so that the delete fails if a referenced row would be orphaned.  If the SP is used consistently, orphans will never occur.

Comment: That's a separate argument: yes, cascading foreign key have their own issues, but either way the foreign key needs to be checked (to ensure it is not violated even if there is no cascade), so the indexing is always going to be an issue